# GitHub action to check out repo as a git submodule

Tags: git, github, github-actions

## Background

I have a project which contains a git sub-module, both are hosted on GitHub.
The sub-module sources are built as part of the project, and changes in the sub-module could affect the containing project.

My goal is to make sure the sub-module does not break the containing project.
For that purpose I'm trying to create a GitHub action **on the submodule repo** that does the following upon push/pull:

- Clone the containing project
- Check out the submodule with the specific push/PR SHA
- Build the project with the submodule

## The problem

The standard [Checkout v2](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action does not support such workflow.
Instead, I'm cloning and checking out the submodule according to `$GITHUB_SHA`, like this:

```
- name: Checkout project
  run: git clone <Project>
- name: Update submodules
  run: git submodule update --init --recursive
- name: Checkout submodule
  working-directory: ./<submodule dir>
      run: |
        git fetch
        git checkout $GITHUB_SHA
- name: Build
  run : make
```

This works well for push, **but not for pull requests**.
On PRs I'm getting something like this:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 48fd1d918a25e7544969d13949b1d436f525412c
```

The SHA that is provided by `$GITHUB_SHA` in case of PRs is simply nowhere to be found.

## Example

- [The action](https://github.com/lvgl/lvgl/actions/runs/244060897/workflow)
- [A failing run](https://github.com/lvgl/lvgl/runs/1084374015?check_suite_focus=true)

## Questions

- Why is `$GITHUB_SHA` wrong in case of PRs? What does it represent in case of PRs?
- Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

---

## Clarification

If it wasn't clear - the problematic PR was on the repo of the **sub-module**, not on the main (containing) project repo.
The action is running on the sub-module repo, and checkouts both the containing and the sub module.

The issue is related to the fact that the `$GITHUB_SHA` of the PR (of the submodule) does not seem to represent a commit on the submodule, although I expected it would.

---

## Update 1

I've made another attempt:
Tried this as the Checkout submodule "run" step:

```
        git fetch ${{ github.event.repository.git_url }}
        git fetch ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.clone_url }}
        git checkout ${{ github.sha }} || git checkout ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

On PR, checkout of both SHAs is still failing with:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree
```

So fetching from the original repo where the PR came from - didn't help.
The `pull_request.head.sha` looks correct (it's the right SHA this time), but `git checkout` even for that fails! No idea why.

---

## Update 2

**Eventually I found a workaround to do it!**
Here is the "Checkout submodule" run step:

```
      run: |
        git fetch --force ${{ github.event.repository.git_url }} "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
        git fetch --force ${{ github.event.repository.git_url }} "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"
        git checkout ${{ github.sha }} || git checkout ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

So what I'm doing is:

- Fetching heads from `git_url`
- Fetching all PRs from `git_url`
- Trying to checkout `github.sha`. This works for push but not for PR
- If the above failed, checkout `github.event.pull_request.head.sha`. This works for PR but not for push....

Same questions, however, remain -

- Why is `github.sha` wrong in case of PRs? What does it represent in case of PRs?
- Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, instead of fetching all PRs from the remote and trying out both `github.sha` and `github.event.pull_request.head.sha`?

Comment: Can you do in your  Checkout submodule "run" step a `git status` and `git remote -v`, just to check you are in the right working folder?

Comment: @VonC `git remote -v` is irrelevant because I'm not using named remotes, I'm providing the full URL for a remote. The fetch commands complete successfully. `git status` returns: `HEAD detached at ...` and `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

Comment: Is it possible the $GITHUB_SHA is part of a PR branch, which is not part of the default refspec? (as illustrated here: https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247). Can you add a remote, then `git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"`, then `git fetch`?

Comment: @VonC Finally I found a workaround, by fetching PRs and trying both SHAs provided by GitHub context, see "Update 2".  I'm not adding this as an answer because it raises more questions than answers...

Comment: @VonC Ok I think I've cracked it! See my answer.

Comment: Good job! I have deleted my answer, which was just noise at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://frontside.com/blog/2020-05-26-github-actions-pull_request/#how-does-pull_request-affect-actionscheckout

Apparently, in case of PR, `github.sha` (or `$GITHUB_SHA`) represents the SHA of the resulting commit that was **created from merging the base to the head**, and not the SHA of the base change commit itself.

To obtain it, I needed to fetch `refs/pull/*/merge` instead of `refs/pull/*/head`.

Now this run step makes more sense:

```
        git fetch --force ${{ github.event.repository.git_url }} "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
        git fetch --force ${{ github.event.repository.git_url }} "+refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"
        git checkout ${{ github.sha }}
```

The first fetch would fetch heads, for push actions. The second would fetch the merge commits for PRs.
Both are represented by `github.sha`.